# How to print a very large value in c

Tags: c

I am newbie, please bear if my question is silly.

```
int main()
{
  int x=60674;
  printf("%lf \n",(double)(x*x));
  printf("%lld \n",(long long)(x*x));
  return 0;
}
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Because `x * x` overflows.

Comment: 1. Be more specific when something "does not work". Explain what you did expect and what you did see. 2. You cast the result but the result is an int. The cast has to be done before.

Comment: You should accept the best answer, not just comment that it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionaly you may use standardised ints:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        int x=60674;
        printf("%" PRIu64 "\n",(uint64_t)x * x);
        return 0;
}
```

Moreover you do not need to cast both variables .. the * will impose using the bigger type of the two multipliers.

Btw you could just use unsigned int .. the result would fit in UINT_MAX which is 4294967295 (from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/limits_h.htm) )

Comment: `UINT_MAX` is at least _65535_ per the C spec  C11 §5.2.4.2.1 1.  C does not specify `UINT_MAX` as `4294967295`.

Answer (score 5):

`x * x` overflows, so you should cast them into `long longs` before the multiplication:

```
printf("%lld \n",((long long)x * (long long)x));
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Solved

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a signed integer that can hold value only upto `-2,147,483,847` to `+2,147,483,847` and on performing the operation

```
    x * x
==> 60674 * 60674 = 3,681,334,276
```

which generally overflows the integer range. Hence you might need some big data type to hold that calculation `60674 * 60674`

You can try two things to do that.

1. Change the data type of `x` from `int` to `long` or for more range `long long`

   `long long x = 60674;`
2. Type cast the calculation to long range data type. 
   `printf("%lld \n",((long long)x* (long long)x));`

Comment: @maharshikintada, you can eventually click on accept answer, if this helped you. Doing this will make me smile :)